# Error installing Dart Development version on OS X with homebrew

Tags: dart, homebrew

Have installed several versions of Dart on OS X using homebrew.

```
brew tap dart-lang/dart
brew install dart
```

Today I did a 'brew upgrade' to Dart 1.11.3 stable, because I want to run cucumber/selenium/chromedriver tests in dartium. Dartium is still at version 39.* and chromedriver wants 40something.

*note: windows users are able to run these tests in dartium :(*

So, tried installing development version 1.12.0-dev.5.0 to see if dartium would also upgrade. No joy

```
brew install dart --devel

Warning: dart-lang/dart/dart-1.11.3 already installed
```

Do I really have to uninstall to install the development version?

Comment: You could try to install it manually using the bwu_dart_archive_downloader package https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bwu_dart_archive_downloader. I haven't tried it on OSX though.

Answer (score 5):

Same thing happened to me too.

I solved it with uninstalling dart first:

```
brew uninstall --force dart
brew install dart --devel --with-dartium --with-content-shell
```

Comment: I went this route as well. Really wanted to be able to ```brew switch``` between versions tho. Thanks.